# flutter\: Unhandled Exception: Concurrent modification during iteration: _LinkedHashMap len:0

Tags: dictionary, flutter, dart

i get this error when i try to remove something from my purchasedItems map which is pf type <String,dynamic>, anyone know why?

```
for (var key2 in purchasedItems.keys) {
  for (var id in currentIds) {
    if (key2 != id) {
      print("key is $key2");
      purchasedItems.removeWhere((key, value) => key == key2);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error means that you are adding or removing objects from a collection during iteration. This is not allowed since adding or removing items will change the collection size and mess up subsequent iteration.

So you cant remove an item in a loop, instead yo can create a list of objects that must be removed and after the loop remove them. Something like this:

```
var toRemove = [];
for (var key2 in purchasedItems.keys) {
  for (var id in currentIds) {
    if (key2 != id) {
      print("key is $key2");
      toRemove.add(key)
    }
  }
}
purchasedItems.removeWhere( (e) => toRemove.contains(e));
```